# Second monitor is not detected after update on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 22.04

I have Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop Lenovo Ideapad 320 and a second monitor connected. And at first, everything worked fine.
Unfortunately after the last update (I believe it included kernel update) and reboot the second monitor is no longer recognised. It's connected via HDMI cable.
I tried to connect this monitor (with this cable) to the Win11 (on another laptop) and it works fine. I don't know what happened to my Ubuntu...

The output of `xrandr --listmonitors` with the monitor plugged in:

```
Monitors: 1
 0: +*eDP-1 1920/344x1080/193+0+0  eDP-1
```

The output of `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo UHD Graphics 620
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Same issue. I upgraded this morning and cannot detect my second monitor.
`xrandr` output:

```
    xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
    Screen 0: minimum 2560 x 1440, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 2560 x 1440
    default connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 0mm x 0mm 2560x1440     93.00*
```

`lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"` output:

```
    09:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 [GeForce GTX 980 Ti] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GM200 [GeForce GTX 980 Ti]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I tried.